# Cheerio returns undefined when calling .each() on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, cheerio

I want to make a request to website, get its html, and give it to cheerio. I need to get all the `"href"` attribute of all the elements with class `".thumb"`. I'm showing the results on the console and I just get undefined many times, I assume it's for each element found. I get undefined when trying to loop through any other element with tag or identifier, but if I don't loop and just get the first one the correct value is given.

```
  function firstReq(){
    req(url, (err,res,html)=>{
       if(err){console.error(err);}
       var $ = cheerio.load(html);
       var arr = []
       $("a").each(()=>{
         console.log($(this).attr("href"));
       });
    });
  }
```

I tried `console.log(html)` to check that the document was alright and it is. I also tried setting `setTimeout` on the iteration, maybe to give `"request"` and `"cheerio"` time to load the file, and still the same. I tried first downloading the html file from the `url` to my computer (outside of function, before call) and then passing it to cheerio, and still undefined.

It's my first personal project with Node and I'm very confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe the problem is using `this` inside an arrow function. Either switch to a keyword function, or make the function accept an argument `$("a").each( element => { console.log($(element).attr("href")) })`

Comment: Adding onto @Sidney, you can use `.each((i, elem) => {...})` if you want to use arrow functions. `elem === this` in that case.

Comment: @Sidney - Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: This answers helped me, thank you. I thought arrow functions worked exactly as normal ones.

Answer (score 2):

U can use two ways [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

Arrow function

```
function firstReq(){
   req(url, (err,res,html)=>{
     if(err){console.error(err);}
     var $ = cheerio.load(html);
     var arr = []
     $("a").each((i , elem)=>{
       console.log($(elem).attr("href"));
     });
   });
}
```

Or function:

```
function firstReq(){
   req(url, (err,res,html)=>{
     if(err){console.error(err);}
     var $ = cheerio.load(html);
     var arr = []
     $("a").each(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr("href"));
     });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request(url, (err,res,html)=>{
       if(err){console.error(err);}
       var $ = cheerio.load(html);
       var arr = []
       $("a").each((index,a)=>{
         console.log($(a).attr("href"));
       });
    });
```